# Unable to run scripts as sudo with the www-data user in Debian

Tags: sudo, raspberry-pi, python3, nftables

I am setting up a captive portal on a Raspberry Pi (latest distro CLI) where my web application will change NFTables rules based on who is logged in. I have a LEMP stack set up; with Laravel 8 as the PHP framework.

Nginx/php user is `www-data`, this user has a sudoers file setup with `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/vportal.getvs.net/app/Python/vportal.py`

The following `ls -al` for the python script: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi www-data  765 Dec 21 11:19 vportal.py`

**In the Laravel Controller code:**

```php
        $process = new Process(['python3','/var/www/vportal.getvs.net/app/Python/vportal.py']);
        $process->run(); // executes after the command finishes

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
         }
         echo $process->getOutput();
```

**The Python script**:

```py
import subprocess
#import os
#import pwd
#print(pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name)
subprocess.run("sudo nft add table nat", shell=True)
subprocess.run("sudo nft 'add chain nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100; }'", shell=True)
subprocess.run("sudo nft add rule ip nat postrouting oifname \"wlan0\" masquerade", shell=True)
subprocess.run("sudo nft add table ip filter", shell=True)
subprocess.run("sudo nft 'add chain ip filter forward { type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept; }'", shell=True)
subprocess.run("sudo nft add rule ip filter forward iifname \"wlan0\" oifname \"wlx000e3b337325\" ct state related,established  accept", shell=True)
subprocess.run("sudo nft add rule ip filter forward iifname \"wlx000e3b337325\" oifname \"wlan0\" accept", shell=True)
```

The idea is to have a route in Laravel 8 trigger the python script through the process command from Symfony on a particular route with the controller. I can run commands that don't require sudo without issues, but my scripts dont want anything to do with sudo. Is there a way to allow `www-data` to run a specific script "safely" with sudo privileges?

Note: this is only used on a local network and won't touch the internet. Not that it's any less of a risk that way, but I figured I would at least note this.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Others have already answered the sudo question, but is there any reason why you want to use python to (clumsily) emulate a shell script? Unless your script is doing other stuff that actually requires python, you'd be better off simplifying this to just a shell script. BTW, you'll also need a `#!` line so that the kernel knows which interpreter to use to run the script (defaults to `/bin/sh` if unspecified). You want www-data to run your script as root, NOT python with your script as an argument. As @roiama mentioned, you **really** don't want www-data to be able to run python itself as root.

Comment: I suppose it does not really need to be Python at this point. I figured there would not be much of a difference from bash to python, and since I use python for other things I would apply it here. For instance, the project is eventually going to be rather large and I may just need Python for other functionality. For now I am okay with breaking it up into bash scripts, however this does not fix my super user issue since nft requires it with these specific commands. It is being ran from a web application (Laravel) which is initiated on an endpoint hit. (after user is authenticated)

Comment: Write scripts that do what you need, break up those scripts into the parts that **need** to be run as root (these should be as small and simple as possible) and the parts that don't (everything else).  Allow www-data to run some of those scripts as root (and mostly the root parts shouldn't be run directly by the web server, they should be run by wrapper scripts that validate and sanitise their input).  Before doing that read up on web security.  Understand that trusting user-supplied data is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant specific users the ability to run specific commands with sudo using sudoers files that you place under `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

The format for this that you could use is:

`user  host=(who to run as) [Options] Command`

Note: You should do all of your editing in visudo.

So if you wanted to give the www-data the privilege to run all `nft` as root you could create the file `/etc/sudoers.d/www-data` with the following contents:

```
www-data ALL = (root) nft
```

Since this is in a script, you probably do not want to be prompted for a password.

In this case you will want to add the NOPASSWD: option:

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: nft
```

In the event that you only wanted to allow `nft add` you could do the following:

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: nft add*
```

And in the event that you wanted to allow the www-data user to run more than just one command as root you can comma separate the commands:

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: nft, ls, cat
```

This would allow www-data to sudo nft or ls or cat without a password.

Note: be careful when editing sudoers files. In the event that your syntax is incorrect any sudo command by any user will error out.

You can use `visudo -c sudofile` to validate the file. So for the example file I've been using `visudo -c /etc/sudoers.d/www-data`. If that commands outputs `www-data: parsed OK` then the syntax is correct.

Comment: This is exactly it. In my case nft is under /usr/sbin/nft. So for example the `/etc/sudoers.d/www-data` file reads `www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/nft add*` Thank you!!

Comment: Perfect! Glad to help.

Comment: Additional note for those who stumble across this post: you can use `type nft` to find your location.

Comment: `sudo nft` for the web user could allow someone to open inbound connections to unprotected services. I wouldn't recommend it myself

Comment: The best thing is to use a wrapper sanitizing what's really allowed. sudo would call the wrapper and the wrapper would only allow some features (eg, a shell script allowing only  a few possibilities present in a case ... esac and never relying on untrusted user input)

Answer (score 1):

You have a **major security flaw** in your `sudoers` file, that allows your web user to run any python file anywhere on the system with root privileges. Consider if that file contained a call to connect `bash` to a network socket:

> ```
> www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/vportal.getvs.net/app/Python/vportal.py, /usr/bin/python3
> ```

Remove the `/usr/bin/python3` as soon as you can.

Now you've done that, let's see why the requirement is failing. You've allowed a specific script, `vportal.py` to run under `sudo`. But you don't ever call it with `sudo`; instead, you have several lines in the script itself that execute `sudo nft […]`, and `nft` is (correctly) not permitted to be run as root by www-data.

Resolve the problem by removing the `sudo` commands from inside your script, and calling the script itself with `sudo`. Oh, and ensure that neither the script itself nor any of the parent directories are writable by the `www-user` account.

Comment: I went ahead and removed that snippet in the original post, just in case someone would happen across it trying random code and not bother reading the solutions below the first one. Good call on that, I was getting desperate trying to find solutions quickly, and forgot I left that in there! As you've explained, there was no reason for it in the first place. I'm reading up more on the sudeors files and how it all works so that does not happen again, as I suggest anyone who isn't familiar do anyways!